# False discovery rate for across independent models with the same explanatory variables

Tags: r, linear-model, model-selection, false-discovery-rate

I have a dataset of >10000 gene expression profiles and I would like to test the effect of 3 explanatory variables and their interactions on each gene expression profile using information criterion (let's say AIC) by automatic model selection (e.g. glmutli R package). I am aware of false positive results of repeated tests. Is there any way to account for false discovery rate? I assume that, FDR could be the critical issue here.

Comment: If you want to control the FDR, then consider using the [knockoff filter](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/FDR_regression.pdf).

Comment: Thank you @Gumeo. The suggested paper is about variable selection within the regression analysis that is not my issue. I am interested to account for false positive results in >10000 regressions (one regression for each gene expression profiles) using the same explanatory variable set. Is there any way to account for it?

Comment: They have implemented a GWAS knockoff [here](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/HighDimKnockoffs.pdf). Otherwise, since you want to include three variables+interactions, you'll have to do a Bonferroni correction, and since you have the 3 variables and some interactions, you will have to multiply each $p$-value by at least 30000 to control the family-wise error rate. That is rather conservative, but the easiest way to try this out.